# Not able to click on bottom menu text

Tags: eclipse, appium, eclipse-oxygen

I am using Appium code with Eclipse Oxygen and write now, I am on Home screen and now I have to tap on account button from the bottom menu, but I am getting error would you please help me out with code. I give you 2 code please help me out.

1)

```
driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Account']").isDisplayed();
driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Account']").click();
```

2)

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@content-desc=\"Account\"]")).click();
```

[image]

Comment: Please add the error output so that we can see what is happening

Comment: I am not getting any error, that's why I am asking for code, if you give me code related this issue then it would be helpfull for me

Comment: Well in your post you say " but I am getting error would you please help me out ". So which error is it?

Comment: You may also include an inspection snapshot in case the issue is that you are not finding the element